# iOS: Unable to play my sounds when silent mode on

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio, audiotoolbox

So I've already gone through most of the relevant question on SO that I could find, yet I still can't get my audio playing while silent.  I believe that it's probably a small error I'm making.

I'm trying to play a small alert sound.  This is the code in my `viewDidLoad` method :

```
AudioSessionInitialize (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
AudioSessionSetActive(true);
```

And here is the method I call when I need to play an audio clip

```
-(void)playAudioClip:(CFStringRef)clip{

CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef soundFile = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, clip, CFSTR("wav"), NULL);

//Supposed to make sound playable even when silent right?
UInt32 soundType = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback; 
UInt32 soundID;

AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(soundType), &soundType);
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFile, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystmSound(soundID);
}
```

I got most of this off SO and confirmed it in the Apple programming guides.  I have already tried combining the `Uint32` for both uses but this didn't do anything either, still no play in locked/silent mode.  Any ideas?

Comment: Silent mode is made for silence...

Comment: Read the documentation about [AudioServicesPlaySystemSound](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioServicesPlaySystemSound)

Comment: @Joe I've read that, and I'm not entirely sure what I'm supposed to get out of it.

Comment: @RobCaraway It was not designed for what you were trying to do, it is more for things like an alert when a SMS or email comes in. When the silent switch is on those do not get played either. It is (vaguely) documented on this line `Sounds play at the current system audio volume, with no programmatic volume control available`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System sounds do not play while in silent mode.  (As the name would suggest)  If you need to play audio while silent you need to use a different method like a media player or other audio method.  Look at Apple's examples for playing music.